# Unable to parse the response string using json parser

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I am using PHP services in my application i am getting the response from server i tried to parse the response string but JSON Parser returns NULL value.  i am unable to parse this response string. i have goggling for this problem but no one give the exact solutions. i am using `SBJson` parser and `NSJSONSeralization` but it returns null value. i am posting my response string below please help me any one. 
Response String is

```
([["{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}"]])
```

Comment: your PHP services using `json_encode` function ?

Comment: How to convert the exact format from this string

Comment: Are you sure the response string is exactly as you printed?

Comment: Once Again i am sending to you my response string. Can you please feel free.[["{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}","{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"7\"}","{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"5\"}","{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}","{\"category_id\":\"4\", \"category_name\":\"ALA CARTE\", \"image_id\":\"2\"}","{\"category_id\":\"5\", \"category_name\":\"LUNCH\", \"image_id\":\"3\"}"]]

Comment: This looks different now: the enclosing parenthesis `(` and `)` are now omitted. Taken literally, this still isn't JSON: the escaped double quotes are bogus, e.g. `... \"category_id\" ...`  Can you edit your post and show exactly how you log the response which is a NSData originally and what's then printed in the console. (Hint: you need to convert the NSData to a NSString first, before printing to the console)

Comment: yes i have converted data to string after that i printed string on console

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you parsing your json as in code below:

```
NSString * jsonString = @"{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}";
NSData * jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonContainer = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                     error:nil];
```

Comment: it's working for single dictionary but it's working for multiple dictionary. actual my response is coming like this.   "{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"7\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"5\"}",
        "{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}",

Comment: it is a list of strings. Valid json string will looks like: `@"[\n{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}, \n{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"7\"}, \n{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"5\"}, \n{\"category_id\":\"3\", \"category_name\":\"BREAKFAST\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}\n]"`

Answer (score 0):

This response

`([["{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}"]])`

is not proper JSON. It occurs, the server "wanted" to send JSON but didn't get it right ;)   -- or you failed to print out a JSON correctly.

The JSON should probably look like:

```
[[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"BEVERAGES","image_id":"6"}]]
```

or

```
[[{"category_id":1,"category_name":"BEVERAGES","image_id":6}]]
```

Note: the key/value pairs might be reordered.

Additionally, ensure you specify the correct `Accept` header value, e.g. "application/json" in your request (**caution**: was incorrect before edit).

And, check status code (should be `200 (OK)`) and the *MIME type* of the response before you attempt to parse the response with a JSON parser. If you expect JSON, you should get a Content-Type header (see also property `MIMEType` of the NSURLResponse) whose value should be `application/json`.

Comment: MIME Type is text/html

Comment: @Murali `text/html` should not be parsed as JSON. However, `([["{\"category_id\":\"1\", \"category_name\":\"BEVERAGES\", \"image_id\":\"6\"}"]])`  doesn't look like html either.

Comment: i am not understanding this response from the morning onwards i am working on this. still i aim unable to do. i am getting that response. i have checked many times but same response. MIME Type:text/html

Comment: @Murali Did you set the Content-Type header of your _request_ to `application/json` ?

Comment: Yes i given same    NSURL *ur = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.9:8081/api.php?mode=getappinfo&nodeid=1"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:ur];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"accept"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    [urlConnection start];

Comment: @Murali **Fix**: I meant setting the `Accept` header in your request, not `Content-Type` header (to @"application/json"). But you need to _check_ for the `Content-Type` header for the _response_ (via property `MIMEType`). It should be "application/json". Please see my edit.

Comment: @Murali You only set the "Content-Type" header in a request when you send data to the server, e.g. via a POST request.

Answer (score -1):

Best fix would be to fix it on the server end and encoded properly.

If this is not possible use `[jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@""];`